# Terminate subprocess in Windows, access denied

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, terminate

-

```
import time
import subprocess
from os.path import expanduser

chrome_path = expanduser('~\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')

proc = subprocess.Popen(chrome_path)
time.sleep(4)
proc.terminate()
```

Output:  `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`

How can I kill the Chrome process?

Python 2.6 on Windows XP.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. I'm using Python 2.6.6 and 6.0.472.63 on Windows 7, but the process gets killed just fine.

Comment: Guess it's just an XP issue then.  I added version info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happens if you use TASKKILL /F /PID [number of process ID] ? Give it a try. Launch it through import OS

Comment: Not sure I understand...  'TASKKILL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ah, apparently taskkill only comes with XP Pro.  I'm running Home edition.  "tskill <pid>" does work, however.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Windows, but have noticed on Linux that Google Chrome "protects" itself from operating system control signals in a way that few programs do:

```
$ ps -lp 2345
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000  2345     1  0  80   0 - 17699 skb_re ?        00:00:00 chrome
$ kill -TERM 2345
$ kill -HUP 2345
$ kill -SEGV 2345
$ ps -lp 2345
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000  2345     1  0  80   0 - 17699 skb_re ?        00:00:00 chrome
```

I suspect this may be the root cause of your troubles. Incidentally, I'm posting this note from process 2345.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet is to find and close the window at the os level:  http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html.