# WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: python

I've been trying to kill a process but all my options give me a Windows Access Denied Error. 
I open the process(a python script) through `test= subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "testsc.py"])` and I want to kill that process.

So far, I've tried `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGILL)` , `os.kill(pid, 9)`, `test.Terminate()` and simply `test.kill()`. All of these give me the error.

I am using Python 2.7.1.4 on a Windows 7 x86 machine. I would appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: We need more code. Maybe the process is already done when you are trying to kill it.

Comment: There seem to be a number of such reports, e.g. [this one with the same title minus a colon and with a lowercase E](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005437/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied) and [this one with a decent name ("Terminate subprocess in Windows, access denied")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868129/terminate-subprocess-in-windows-access-denied).

Comment: Observing the documentation for [os.kill](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill), "New in version 2.7: Windows support". But you say you're using Python 2.7 so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What process are you trying to kill? Did you spawn it? If it's a SYSTEM process, you won't be able to kill it as a local admin.

Comment: @Josh: did you *read*? `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "testsc.py"])`. He should be able to kill that!

Comment: @Chris my mistake - for some reason I had it in my head he was attaching to the process instead of spawning it, idk what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround if anyone interested - even as an admin I get access denied on some services when using `os.kill`. however, this works:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("Taskkill /PID %d /F" % pid)
```

So if you don't care about being cross-platform and want a quick and dirty solution - try this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, it means that access is denied. You don't have permission to kill the process. This could be due to your account level (a "guest" sort of account or an account restricted by group policy) or it could be due to UAC (admin on your own machine but not running as admin—not sure if Windows 7 allows non-elevated process killing, though I would have thought it would).

Comment: I am an admin on the pc and I am logged in as that user. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: @dawnoflife: but if you haven't disabled UAC, are you running the process in elevated state?

Comment: I am not totally sure what you are referring to here. Let me google disabling UAC first.

Comment: If you are admin, though, I wouldn't expect it to require UAC elevation. I think I'm probably barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Yeah i looked it up and if I'm the admin then it should already be taken care of for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Aah I gave up and just used taskkill instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so i was having the same problem, that you have + having a problem with some annoying api i tought "Well, there is no chance i must install the updates, YES or YES", but no, i did the next.

**Warning**; *Before starting doing the 7th step try to install python when you finish the 6th step, if still not working, try starting with the 7th step.*

1. Install [vcredist_x86](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A-475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe) (if you have 64 bit OS **[install the 64 bits version](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/2/3224B87F-CFA0-4E70-BDA3-3DE650EFEBA5/vcredist_x64.exe)**).
2. Go to My PC.
3. Enter to the local disc (C:/ or whatever letter you have on it).
4. Second click on Users>Properties>Security>Advanced.
5. Owner>Edit>In the change owner to list, select new owner>Clic the option. of "Add changes to all subfolders".
6. Clic ok twice when you finished.
7. Go to permissions.
8. Select your user.
9. Clic full control.
10. Apply changes and close properties then install python.

This worked for me.