# How to terminate process created by Python Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, terminate

I'm running calc.exe (windows 10, python 3.6) using `proc = subprocess.Popen("calc.exe")`, then `time.sleep(time)` and then want to kill process: `os.kill(proc.pid, -9)` or `os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)` gives me error

> "Access Denied".

I also tried proc.terminate - it didn't help.

And I also noticed that proc.pid gives different PID from PID which is shown in task manager. Any ideas how to kill my process?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminate subprocess in Windows, access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868129/terminate-subprocess-in-windows-access-denied)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using windows to kill the process.

```
command = "Taskkill /IM calc.exe /F"
proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

or

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im Calculator.exe /f")
```

If you want to be sure., Try a recursive kill!!

```
def kill_process(proc):
    # Check process is running, Kill it if it is,

    # Try to kill the process - 0 exit code == success

    kill = "TaskKill /IM {} /F".format(proc)

    res = subprocess.run(kill)

    if res == 0:
        return True  # Process Killed
    else:
        kill_process(proc)  # Process not killed repeat until it is!

kill_process('Calculator.exe')
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll try it on Monday and will write you my result. P.S, i've just tried to execute the code i've written on Windows 7 with proc.terminate() and it works! Do you know why it doesn't on Win10?

Comment: Probably something to do with user access rights..Maybe try running the script as `admin`. I had the same problem on windows 10 and had to write this function that does the job..

Comment: It didn't help. A saw in the Task Manager that process was created with the name "Calculator.exe" (not calc.exe). I tried to implement "proc.terminate()" once more - it workswithout errors but when script terminates, calculator is still working:(

Comment: What happens if you run `TaskKill /IM calc.exe /F` from cmd? (Also try Calculator.exe)

Comment: Calculator.exe - terminates successfully, calc.exe gives error: windows can't find such process

Comment: if you try `Calculator.exe` in the python code? what happens?

Comment: it terminates successfully too. And if i execute proc.pid, it gives (for example) 7740 and then when execute os.system("taskkill ...") cmd prints "Process with PID 6612 was terminated" - PID's are different, that's why i think proc.terminate doesn't work :( But how can I get the value 6612 when execute Popen("calc.exe")?

Comment: it looks like I execute "calc.exe" - standart windows's application but it creates "Calculator.exe" and then I know nothing about PID of the "Calculator.exe" from my proc variable

Comment: Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the python 3 subprocess API, one can kill the child by calling

```
Popen.kill()
```

which is an alias for `Popen.terminate()` in Windows ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html?highlight=exp#subprocess.Popen.kill)). If this doesn't work, you can try

`os.system("TASKKILL /F /PID [child PID]")`

You can get the PID of the child with `Popen.pid()`

Comment: thanks! But why proc.pid gives the value which differs from the PID in task manager?